# Получить имя столбца в DataTable

Tags: c#

Выбираю адаптером таблицу из БД. Примерно так :

```
 DataTable table= new DataTable();
 adapter.Fill(table);
 return table;
```

Можно ли получить имя столбца ? Как то так :  `table.Columns[i].`   ?

Comment: ...вам нужно свойство [ColumnName](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datacolumn.columnname(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Можно получать имена столбцов так:

```
foreach (DataColumn column in table.Columns)
    Console.Write(column.ColumnName);
```